# Disconnect automatically a vpn connection after 5 hours

Tags: windows, vpn, disconnect

Is there a way to create a batch file or run some command like shutdown -s -t , where I can include time after which a vpn connection will be disconnected for example after 4 or 5 hours.

My gratitude to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your help. I have found something that may prove more useful in the future, though. It's called Perfect Automation, and I can record any action and set it to run at some specific time.

My thanks extended to the creator of this software as well as to you.

Comment: No problem. You may want to select an answer as the official answer to close this thread. You can press the tick next to the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you start this script up at a similar time that you start the VPN software up:

```
TIMEOUT /T 18000 /NOBREAK
TaskKill /f /IM VPNName.exe
```

This will wait for 5 hours, specified by the 18000 ( the seconds it should wait ) and will then forcefully close your VPN executable. Of course, you must replace VPNName with the executable's name. Also, you should try to change the /t value to test it as 5 hours is a long time to wait to test something.

By the way, this is a batch file.